# How to Eliminate For Loop with a Sliding Overlapping Window in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

Since For Loops are slow in Python, I'd like to avoid them. How can I vectorize or use methods to speedup the code that involve sliding overlapping windows like this?

```
data = np.mgrid[0:6, 0:2].reshape(3,-1).T
window_length=3
value = np.zeros(len(data) - window_length + 1)


for j in range(0,len(data)-window_length):
    window_mean = np.mean(data[j:j + window_length,:], axis=1)
    for k in range(j, j + window_length):
        #just some operation  
        value[j] = np.matmul(np.transpose(data[k,:]), data[k, :] + window_mean)
```

Comment: `df.rolling(window_length).mean()`?

Comment: Thanks. That will only compute the mean. What about the other custom operations?

Comment: Note quite sure if that help you but by googling "why for loops are slow in python", I came across [this](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) article. Good read, and maybe interesting for you. Tldr; Reduce the number of function lookups and use C implemented internals.